# AJAX Refresh - Duplicates already loaded Data from Database

Tags: php, ajax

On the current page I've been working on, I've set the code out in a way that it would work as a live blog / update kind of system. The problem is, I load the stuff in from my database in my PHP, then I have AJAX which links to another file which will get the database content and refresh the area it is contained in on my site.

Thus' meaning it will auto-update every 15000 miliseconds with the data from the database. The Problem is, it already has the existing data loaded in. So no matter what. every 15000 milisecond it will refresh that div, so data that is already on the page will be duplicated.

**More Clear Bulletpoint form**

- PHP queries database, echo's out the data.
- AJAX checks another php page every 15000 miliseconds and echo's that out onto the first page.
- Instead of only posting new content, it simply duplicates the original content. (Can have double posts or even tripple. It seems to vary)

I'm only really getting into PHP, I haven't put much time into it, and my knowledge of AJAX is non-exisistant so it presents problem doing something like this. I've tried searching on how to only echo out the existing data on page one, even though page two is handling the updates.

Here is the code however, sorry if it's messy, or does things in correctly. I am still learning this language.

First Page matchdayupdates.php?id=(in this case the id is 6)

```html
$id = $_GET['id'];
  
 if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
 
    $requestMatchInformation = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM matchinfo WHERE pageid='$id' LIMIT 500");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($requestMatchInformation)) {
        $pageid = $row['pageid'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $postheader = $row['postheader'];
        $postcontent = $row['postcontent'];
        $posttime = $row['posttime'];
        echo "<div class='center-match-container'>
            <div class='match-information'>
                <div class='post-container'>
                    <div class='post-left'>
                        <img class='post-type-icon' src='images/icons/$type' />
                    </div>
                    <div class='post-right'>
                        <h3 class='header-top'>$postheader</h3>
                        <span class='time-red-right'>$posttime</span>
                        <br />
                            <br />
                        <p class='post-content'>$postcontent</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>";        
    }
    
    $requestEventsInformation = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id='$id'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($requestEventsInformation)) {
        $opponent = $row['opponent'];
        $datetime = $row['datetime'];
        $datetimedisplay = $row['datetimedisplay'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        $datepassed = $row['datepassed'];
        $rowonescore = $row['rowonescore'];
        $rowtwoscore = $row['rowtwoscore'];
        $rowoneplayers = $row['rowoneplayers'];
        $rowtwoplayers = $row['rowtwoplayers']; 
    }
    
 }
 else {
 
 }
 
 if(!$requestEventsInformation && !$requestMatchInformation) {
    echo '<div class="match-notice"><h4>There are currently no updates, this page will auto-update when there are new updates.</h4></div>';
 }
 
 echo $id;
 ?>
 <script>
     var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
         $('.center-match-container').fadeOut('slow', function() {
             $(this).load('/esports/match/matchinforequest.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>', function() {
                 $(this).fadeIn('slow');
             });
         });
         $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
     }, 15000);
 </script>
```

Second Page matchinforequest.php?id=(again this id is 6)

```html
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $requestMatchInformation = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM matchinfo WHERE pageid='$id' LIMIT 500");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($requestMatchInformation)) {
        $pageid = $row['pageid'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $postheader = $row['postheader'];
        $postcontent = $row['postcontent'];
        $posttime = $row['posttime'];
        echo "<div class='center-match-container'>
            <div class='match-information'>
                <div class='post-container'>
                    <div class='post-left'>
                        <img class='post-type-icon' src='images/icons/$type' />
                    </div>
                    <div class='post-right'>
                        <h3 class='header-top'>$postheader</h3>
                        <span class='time-red-right'>$posttime</span>
                        <br />
                            <br />
                        <p class='post-content'>$postcontent</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>";
    }

    $requestEventsInformation = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id='$id'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($requestEventsInformation)) {
        $opponent = $row['opponent'];
        $datetime = $row['datetime'];
        $datetimedisplay = $row['datetimedisplay'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        $datepassed = $row['datepassed'];
        $rowonescore = $row['rowonescore'];
        $rowtwoscore = $row['rowtwoscore'];
        $rowoneplayers = $row['rowoneplayers'];
        $rowtwoplayers = $row['rowtwoplayers'];
    }
    echo "Received Data";
}
else {
}
```

Comment: instead of appending the data, replace it... what's the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading the new data into any HTML element with the class `center-match-container`, but the new data you get with AJAX also contains an element with the class `center-match-container`, so the second call loads it into two places and so on.

In `matchinforequest.php` remove `<div class='center-match-container'>` and the corresponding `</div>` and it should work.

As a side note, you are not using prepared statements, but instead putting the contents of $_GET['id'] directly into your database query. This means someone could easily wipe your database by setting `id` to something like `0'; DELETE FROM matchinfo; '`. Please look into prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and update your code to avoid this security risk!

Comment: Hmmm.... I just removed the `center-match-container` and it still duplicated it, when it got the new data. I also tried removing `.match-container` and it also duplicated after that as well. I'll also check out the prepared statements now and make sure my code is secure.

Comment: Do you have multiple entries in the database? Try including a counter in `matchinforequest.php ` (`$count = 0;` before the `SELECT`, then `$count++;` right after the while and in before you echo `$postheader` echo `Row count is $count`) to check.

Comment: Where would the first part go, the `$count = 0;` doesn't work inside of the speech marks / mysqli statement. Then if it's before the speech marks it throws up a Syntax Error.

Comment: On the line before `$requestMatchInformation = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT ...`

Comment: I've just echo'd out the $count variable and it says "1" here is a screenshot of the database it is getting the stuff from, in-case that is helpful.

http://prntscr.com/aokx4y

Comment: I tried a simulation of the same thing, with the `center-match-container` div removed from `matchinforequest.php` and it seemed to work for me. The duplication you are talking about does sound like each time it loads new html with a new div with that class. Does that description make sense to you and as to why it would happen?

Comment: Well I just removed it. I reloaded the page, it displays the 3 rows from the database, however when the AJAX reloads the div I end up with 9 rows... 3 duplicates. Also, there ends up being 3 divs with the class `center-match-container` so I'm gathering that that issue revolves around that.

Comment: aha, the problem is that the ajax loads the results into *each* div with the center-match-container class. Try instead putting in a new div with `id="center-match-container-wrapper"` in `matchdayupdates.php`, starting before the first query and ending after the while loop form the last query, then change the code in the `setInterval` call to load into the wrapper div `$('#center-match-container-wrapper').fadeOut(....`. You should also put the `center-match-container` div back into `matchinforequest.php`

Comment: Huzzah! It works perfectly. Thank you! :-) Edit: :-( Won't let me Up-vote you because of my rep.